# Netbeans JAVA MYSQL DB strange behavior - Can't retrieve data after closing the app - JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, netbeans

After my laptop crashed last week I decided to the netbeans environment in order to be able to work on my java project on my desktop computer.

Everything was fine on my laptop, my project was running fine (communication between my java app and my database was OK).

So I reinstalled everything on my desktop computer (using the official tutorial)

- MySQL Server
- MySQL Connection for JAVA (placing the jar file in the ext folder)
- NetBeans 8.1

The problem is that I can still connect to my database using my app, the connection is successfull but when writing data in the database I can't see them using MySQL Workbench or the embedded SQL viewer in NetBeans.
But inside the app I can access to these datas!

Accessing to the data still work though. (I can add data through MySQL Workbench and access to these data using my app).

I placed try-catch to catch every errors that could come over but there is not.
I don't have any error showing up (no SQLException).

```
    try {
    connect.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO COMPTE(TYPECPTE,VALINITIALE,SOLDE,NUMEROCPTE) VALUES('test',4,2,8)");

    ResultSet result = connect.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM compte WHERE NUMEROCPTE = 8");

    if (result.next()) javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"8 IS HERE - I FOUND IT"); 
    else javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"8 IS NOT HERE - CANT FIND IT"); 

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code returns me "**8 IS HERE - I FOUND IT**". But when I look at the database I can't find the line with "8" inside.

Can someone tell me what's going on ?

Comment: Can u please try it after adding conn.commit after your insert and see if it mama any difference

Comment: It worked. Setautocommit was set to false this is why I couldn't see the data in the DB. Thanks a lot for your answer, problem solved !

Comment: Can you please up vote my answer and comment thanks

Comment: You are leaking resource by creating a statement without closing it.

Comment: I can't upvote your comment I need 15 reputation... If you find a solution for me to vote for your answer I will definitely !!

Answer (score 0):

Setautocommit was set to false this is why I couldn't see the data in the DB. Adding conn.commit(); after every update, insert and delete queries worked.